# Cloudwatch API: How to use multiple AWS accounts

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to get the cpu utilization for ec2 instances for an account. My code is like following.

```
    def GetRegions():
        return array of regions

    def getEC2InstanceID(RegionName):
         cloudwatch = boto3.client('cloudwatch', region_name=RegionName)
         response = cloudwatch.get_metric_statistics(
         .
         .
         .)
        returns array of ec2instanceID

    def EC2_Average_Utilization(InstanceID, RegionName):
        returns avg cpuusage 


def main():
    regions= GetRegions()
    for i in range(len(regions)):
        print(regions[i])
        instance_id = getEC2InstanceID(regions[i])
        print(instance_id)  # prints all the instances if there is any
        if (type(instance_id)==list):
            for j in range(len(instance_id)):
                print(instance_id[j])
                print ("For InstanceID "+ instance_id[j] +  ":")
                EC2_Average_Utilization(instance_id[j], regions[i])
```

This code executes perfectly for all the regions under only one account. If I want to do the same thing for multiple AWS accounts, what will be the procedure?

n.b  I've seen configuring the .aws/config by creating multiple profiles under every account in .aws/credentials, but as I'm generating the regions in the code, I don't want to specify them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use a boto3 `Session` object, the 'Security Token Service (STS)', and a call to `assume_role` for each account/region combo. The effect is the same as the named profile - you need a role in each account with adequate permissions to call the API methods (EC2, CloudWatch, etc). Also, the target roles need a trust relationship back to the original account credentials.

```
sts = boto3.client('sts')

#this is called with your default credentials. Target roles need to trust this identity
creds = sts.assume_role(RoleArn='...', RoleSessionName='...')

# set up a session w/ the temporary credentials
session = boto3.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=creds['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
    aws_secret_access_key=creds['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
    aws_session_token=creds['Credentials']['SessionToken']
    region_name='...')

# all subsequent clients/resources should be instantiated from the session object
cloudwatch = session.client('cloudwatch')
```

Hope this helps.

See https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sts.html#STS.Client.assume_role